# JS Array - convert string to key

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexing

Edit : thanks, I misused the eval function, now this works fine that way :
eval('foo'+bar), instated of foo[eval(bar)] or eval(foo[bar]). This was very simple finally...

---

For some reasons, I have to convert a string to a valid index to access elements in a complex multidimensionnal array. For example, let's say I have this :

```
var foo = [
    [1,2,3],
    [
        4,
        [5,6]
    ]
];

var bar  =  [
    1: "[0][0]", 
    2: "[0][1]", 
    3: "[0][2]", 
    4: "[1][0]", 
    5: "[1][1][0]", 
    6: "[1][1][1]"
];

var selectVal5 = foo[bar[5]];
```

I tried few `eval()` tricks, but it doesn't seem to work. So, any idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of multidimensional array, you can use

```
eval('foo' + bar).
```

This will return right the content without any brackets. If no, you may use regex to extract dimensions from  string, like

```
bar.match(/[0-9]+/g).
```

Comment: Yep, looks to work fine, the mistake I made was to double the [] foo[[0][0]], thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple eval and it works.

```
var foo = [
    ['val1','val2'],
    ['val3']
];
var bar  = "[1][0]";
foo[eval(bar)].toString(); //added to String so that the brackets can be removed
```

Comment: You're right, I wanted to simplify my problem, but it doesn't represent the real issue. I just edited my post to make it accurate, sorry about that !

Answer (score 0):

It works using `eval` and `String`:

```
<input type="button" value="test" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

This is the script:

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    var foo = [
    ['val1','val2'],
    ['val3']
    ];
    var bar  = "[1][0]";
    var selectVal3 = String(foo[eval(bar)]);

    $("#result").append(selectVal3);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/